# Inconsistant 0x8004100C Error WBEM_E_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

this code run:

Win7 OK
Win8 Error
Win10 some ok / some error
Error Code 0x8004100C
In Microsoft-library：

> WBEM_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
>       2147749900 (0x8004100C)
>       Feature or operation is not supported.

My code:

```
Dim i,j,k,items(100),threshold(100),smartdata(10,11),t
Dim Des(10),Limit(10),Normal(10),Bad(10),Data(10),getinfo(10),status(10)
Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colItems,objItem

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\WMI")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictThresholds",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 'error line
    j=0
    For i=2 To UBound(objItem.VendorSpecific,1) Step 12
        items(j) = objItem.VendorSpecific(i)
        threshold(j) = objItem.VendorSpecific(i+1)
        j=j+1
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Interesting question, not found a duplicate would be inclined not to close it *(even though it has a close vote)*. It could still do with some tlc though, it's not the best description of a problem I've ever seen but it's also not the worst.

Comment: The problem is `WBEM_E_NOT_SUPPORTED` is being returned by WMI not VBScript, it entirely depends on the WMI implementation.

Comment: See if the hard drives are SMART enabled.

Comment: @Noodles that is a great comment, you should leave an answer as there isn't already one from what I can see.

Comment: Not sure this question deserves a down-vote, see [reasoning above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072729/inconsistant-0x8004100c-error-wbem-e-not-supported#comment69355309_41072729).

Comment: I no longer follow hardware - I don't know if there are still non - S.M.A.R.T. harddrives.

Comment: @Lankymart,@Noodles,thank you.And I'm so sorry,my english isn't enough to describe this problem.I will see if the hard drives are SMART enabled，thank you.

Comment: If not hard drives then it is S.M.A.R.T enabled drivers that are lacking. Most Mfg implement their own hardware solution so it's not comparable Mfg to Mfg.

Comment: @Noodles，Yeah，It is too hard。I'm going to give up studying this problem.Thank you.